# Using jasmine to test angular. Promises never get resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angular-promise

I have trouble testing a service that uses promises. This code timeout after jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL (5 sec). Seems like jasmine is busy waiting and never let a chance for $timeout to run.

```
angular.module("testmodule", [])
.factory("service", function($timeout) {
  return $timeout(function() {},0);
});

describe("Test module that uses promise", function() {

  beforeEach(module('testmodule'));

  it("should get a promise that get instantly resolved", function(done) {
    inject(function(service) {
      service.then(function() {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: You don't call a *promise*. But you need to *call the function* to actually get the promise!

Comment: @Bergi, are you saying this code is calling a promise ? Instead of calling which function ?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you cannot call promises but only functions - your title is odd. Do you mean that the "promise never resolves" and "the callback doesn't get called"? I don't know angular, are you sure that `service` is a promise and not the function that returns one?

Comment: Sorry for the title, I'll fix it if I can... $timeout returns a promise. The factory function is called internally by Angular and the result (a promise) is injected as the variable service by inject in the unit test. This actually work in production, but the promise is never resolved.

Comment: Hi. I'm facing the same problem. Did you get to a solution?